# Auto Rotations and Fingerprint not available in Fedora 36

Tags: fedora

I just installed Fedora 36 in my Laptop(Lenovo Ideapad Flex 5 ).

My laptop offers 360 degree rotation  and fingerprint scanner. But laptop screen doesnt rotate along with it.

There is no any setting related to it in the system setting.

What should I do ??

Comment: Do you have `iio-sensor-proxy` installed?

Comment: No.. I have not installed any of these.

Comment: And if you do install `iio-sensor-proxy`, will screen rotation work?  It does on my laptop.

Comment: I tried installing iio-sensor-proxy.... It still doesnt work ??..

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: i did.... still not working

Comment: Looks like [this issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/1686) is related/the cause.